# How to redirect sub-domain in laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have to build a simple app in Laravel while registering I accept  **username**  in a registration form. Once user verify their email and login to the app, I want to redirect them to a new subdomain 
`http://{username}.myapp.com` 
How do I achieve this and also there will be more routes under that subdomain.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing

Comment: Please note that the specified url is NOT a valid subdomain, a subdomain must always be seperated with a `.` and not with a `/`, so it should be something like `http://{username}.myapp.com`

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `redirect()` helper:

In your case it could be something like:

```
public function validate(){
    // ...
    $subdomain = '...';
    // ...
    return redirect()->to('http://'.$subdomain.'.'.env('APP_DOMAIN'));
}
```

After that you could put all the subdomain routes in a [sub-domain routing group](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/routing#route-group-sub-domain-routing), the redirect would only be used after a successful login and not on every route

Comment: but doing this everywhere again and again is not a great idea. Any other idea?

Comment: What do you mean with everywhere? You just need to redirect them once after validation you said, after that, they stay under the same subdomain.
Check the link that @Joe sent in order to serve routes under a subdomain.